Langchain, Ollama, and Llama 3 prompt and response
Currently, I am getting back multiple responses, or the model doesn't know when to end a response, and it seems to repeat the system prompt in the response(?). I simply want to get a single response back. My setup is very simple, so I imagine I am missing implementation details, but what can I do to only return the single response?
from langchain_community.llms import Ollama

llm = Ollama(model="llama3")

def get_model_response(user_prompt, system_prompt):
    prompt = f"""
        <|begin_of_text|>
        <|start_header_id|>system<|end_header_id|>
        { system_prompt }
        <|eot_id|>
        <|start_header_id|>user<|end_header_id|>
        { user_prompt }
        <|eot_id|>
        <|start_header_id|>assistant<|end_header_id|>
        """
    response = llm.invoke(prompt)
    return response


Where are you setting the end tokens to stop decoding at?

(separately, and not related to the problem at hand, your prompt has a lot of whitespace that you probably don't want to pay to tokenize and send over the wire).

@CharlesDuffy, I suppose I am not setting end tokens? Where, or how should I? Otherwise, I am running this locally on llama 3 8B.

I don't use ollama, but the very first Google hit -- https://github.com/ollama/ollama/issues/3759 -- looks like a solid place to start. Stop tokens need to be set for the process doing the decoding, telling the code that's getting results out of the LLM (going from probabilities to specific tokens) what to recognize as an indicator that a response is complete and it can stop reading. See the comment reporting setting stop= on the call as successful.

I had already peeked at that @CharlesDuffy. For kicks I threw in a <|eot_id|> at the end, but that didn't stop it.

...and did you try that specific stop=["<|start_header_id|>", "<|end_header_id|>", "<|eot_id|>", "<|reserved_special_token"] argument?

(when you say "threw in a <|eot_id|> at the end", do you mean at the end of the prompt? It doesn't go in the prompt; really, follow the advice given in the ticket comment precisely).

Using a PromptTemplate from Langchain, and setting a stop token for the model, I was able to get a single correct response.
from langchain_community.llms import Ollama
from langchain import PromptTemplate # Added

llm = Ollama(model="llama3", stop=["<|eot_id|>"]) # Added stop token

def get_model_response(user_prompt, system_prompt):
    # NOTE: No f string and no whitespace in curly braces
    template = """
        <|begin_of_text|>
        <|start_header_id|>system<|end_header_id|>
        {system_prompt}
        <|eot_id|>
        <|start_header_id|>user<|end_header_id|>
        {user_prompt}
        <|eot_id|>
        <|start_header_id|>assistant<|end_header_id|>
        """

    # Added prompt template
    prompt = PromptTemplate(
        input_variables=["system_prompt", "user_prompt"],
        template=template
    )
    
    # Modified invoking the model
    response = llm(prompt.format(system_prompt=system_prompt, user_prompt=user_prompt))
    
    return response


Here is a sample code to work with Langchain and LlamaCpp with local model file.
Library insists on using invoke method rather than directly calling "llm(message)"
from langchain_community.llms import LlamaCpp
from langchain_core.prompts import PromptTemplate

llm = LlamaCpp(
    model_path = "C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\models\\QuantFactory\\Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct-GGUF\\Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct.Q3_K_L.gguf",
    n_gpu_layers=-1,
    temperature=0,
    stop=["<|eot_id|>"],
)

template = """
        <|begin_of_text|>
        <|start_header_id|>system<|end_header_id|>
        {system_prompt}
        <|eot_id|>
        <|start_header_id|>user<|end_header_id|>
        {user_prompt}
        <|eot_id|>
        <|start_header_id|>assistant<|end_header_id|>
        """
def get_response(country):
    sys_template_str = "Give a one or two word answers only."
    human_template_str = "What is capital of {country} ?"

    prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(template.format(system_prompt = sys_template_str,
                                                          user_prompt = human_template_str))
    session = prompt | llm 
    response = session.invoke({"country":country})
    print(response)

get_response("Australia")


I'd recommending using the Hugging Face tokenizer.apply_chat_template() function, which automatically applies the correct chat template for the respective model. It's easier than manually writing the chat template and less error prone. Docs: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/chat_templating

You need to collect the responses. For me, this worked:
# Definiere den Prompt
prompt = (
   "your prompt"
)

# Generiere Inhalt mit Ollama
try:
    stream = ollama.generate(
        model="llama3.1",
        prompt=prompt,
        stream=True,
    )
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Fehler beim Generieren des Inhalts:     {e}")
    raise


# Alle Chunks sammeln
full_response = ""

for chunk in stream:
    response = chunk.get('response', '')
    print("Collecting response: " + response)
    full_response += response

# Debug: Drucke die vollständige Antwort
print("Full Response:")
print(full_response)


Your answer may indeed work, but the question is how to do this via Langchain, which your answer doesn't include...
